# How to add `nGram` in elastic search

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I would like to add `ngram` in my elastic search. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html

I had tried this at `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch.php`:

```
/**
 * Create new index with mapping.
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @param string $indexName
 * @param string $mappedIndexerId
 * @return $this
 */
protected function prepareIndex($storeId, $indexName, $mappedIndexerId)
{
    $this->indexBuilder->setStoreId($storeId);
    $settings = $this->indexBuilder->build();
    $allAttributeTypes = $this->fieldMapper->getAllAttributesTypes([
        'entityType' => $mappedIndexerId,
        // Use store id instead of website id from context for save existing fields mapping.
        // In future websiteId will be eliminated due to index stored per store
        'websiteId' => $storeId
    ]);
    $settings['index']['mapping']['total_fields']['limit'] = $this->getMappingTotalFieldsLimit($allAttributeTypes);

    $settings['index']['analysis']['filter']['trigrams_filter'] = [
        'type' => 'ngram',
        'min_gram' => 3,
        'max_gram' => 3
    ];
    $settings['index']['analysis']['analyzer']['trigrams'] = [
        'type' => 'custom',
        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
        'filter' => [
            'lowercase', 'trigrams_filter'
        ]
    ];
    $mappings['product']['properties']['name'] = [
        'type' => 'text',
        'analyzer' => 'trigrams'
    ];
    $this->client->createIndex($indexName, ['settings' => $settings, 'mappings' => $mappings]);

    $this->client->addFieldsMapping(
        $allAttributeTypes,
        $indexName,
        $this->clientConfig->getEntityType()
    );
    $this->preparedIndex[$storeId] = $indexName;
    return $this;
}
```

But this returns following error:

> report.CRITICAL:
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
>   mapping update to [254407_product_1_v61] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [product,
>   document]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
>   mapping update to [254407_product_1_v61] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [product, document]"},"status":400}
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400):
>   {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Rejecting
>   mapping update to [254407_product_1_v61] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [product,
>   document]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Rejecting
>   mapping update to [254407_product_1_v61] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [product, document]\"},\"status\":400} at
>   /vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:636)"}
>   []

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change.

```
$mappings['product']['properties']['name'] = [
        'type' => 'text',
        'analyzer' => 'trigrams'
    ];
```

Replace above code with a statement.

```
$mappings['document']['properties']['name'] = [
            'type' => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'trigrams'
        ];
```

The above code(mentioned in your qn.) may only use for ElasticSearch 2.x,

Refer below code for ElasticSearch 6.x.

```
protected function prepareIndex($storeId, $indexName, $mappedIndexerId)
{
    $this->indexBuilder->setStoreId($storeId);
    $settings = $this->indexBuilder->build();
    $allAttributeTypes = $this->fieldMapper->getAllAttributesTypes([
        'entityType' => $mappedIndexerId,
        // Use store id instead of website id from context for save existing fields mapping.
        // In future websiteId will be eliminated due to index stored per store
        'websiteId' => $storeId
    ]);
    $settings['index']['mapping']['total_fields']['limit'] = $this->getMappingTotalFieldsLimit($allAttributeTypes);
    $settings['index']['analysis']['filter']['trigrams_filter'] = [
        'type' => 'ngram',
        'min_gram' => 3,
        'max_gram' => 3
    ];
    $settings['index']['analysis']['analyzer']['trigrams'] = [
        'type' => 'custom',
        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
        'filter' => [
            'lowercase', 'trigrams_filter'
        ]
    ];

    $this->client->createIndex($indexName, ['settings' => $settings]);
    $this->client->addFieldsMapping(
        $allAttributeTypes,
        $indexName,
        $this->clientConfig->getEntityType()
    );
    $this->preparedIndex[$storeId] = $indexName;
    return $this;
}
```

**EDIT**

You may have to make a change in a Builder.php.

```
$tokenizer = [
    'default_tokenizer' => [
        'type' => 'standard'
    ],
];
```

Replace the above code with below statement.

```
$tokenizer = [
    'default_tokenizer' => [
        'type' => 'ngram'
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but getting this error: Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analysis : {analyzer={custom_analyzer={tokenizer=trigrams_tokenizer}}, tokenizer={trigrams_tokenizer={token_chars=[letter], min_gram=3, type=ngram, .....

Comment: @AdarshKhatri which ES version you use?

Comment: ES version 6.8.5

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, now reindex is running without any error. But my main motto of this to do a partial search. It's still not giving any results. See this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299311/elasticsearch-is-not-able-to-search-5600-when-product-name-has-tw5600