# Magento 2 How to allow special characters like "/" in catalog search?

Tags: magento2.3, search, special-character

Using Magento 2.3, I have 3,000 products that are fittings for a plumbing warehouse. Currently, it is impossible to search for a fitting that is 1/2" or 3/4".

How do I allow special characters like "/" or quotation marks in catalog search?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL provides full text search. Switch catalog search engine to `ElasticSearch 6+` and implement code as per below code - this answer may help you for sure in the case of ElasticSearch - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/300027 based on - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299311